# How to format back private key file?

Tags: linux, bash

We are passing the complete text of private key pem file to our script.

THere in that job, it is saving the pem file from the text passed.

But, somehow the formatting is missing there and because of that the pem file is not working for authentication of servers.

Any suggestion, on how to fix that formatting, any command line tools?

Please don't divert the question to other unnecessary details, but for your clear reference I am giving the below details.

CI tool: gitlab pipeline.
Input: aws ec2 server public IP, private key pem file content(as string data, not file path) to access the instance using ssh.

Inside writing the content of second variable/paramter to a pem file.
After that, trying to access the ec2 instance with the pem file written.

Expected Output: should connect to the machine.
Current Output: getting permission denied.

Any other CI tool also gives similar output.

Comment: There is no way to tell without knowing how it looks like. But instead `fixing` the key file, it might be better to modify how you pass the key, maybe by encoding it in base64 or something similar.

Comment: I tried base64 encode and decode as you suggested.
for testing, encoded using https://www.base64encode.org/ and also from command line and decoded using ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY=$(echo $ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY | base64 --decode) but still same formatting issue, and getting permission denied

Comment: As I said, without knowing what exactly you are doing there is no way to help you.

Comment: Rephrased the same details again in detail in the above content, for your reference

Comment: Okay, let me be clear. If you want help you need to post the code you've written to do that, along with an example of the mangled key.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider what code? I told clearly the input variable is passed with key as text and it is removing all linebreaks and formatting, you can try it with a simple echo command also in gitlab ci pipelines/jenkins.